# How do I clear the textarea's value when clicked on the addbtn in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I used the following code, but the text does not clear when I click the addbtn.
This is a reactjs project.

```
function Addpage() {

    const[note, setnote] = useState("");
    function textchange(e) {
        setnote(e.target.value);
        console.log(note);
    };
    
        function savenote(){
        localStorage.setItem('savednotes', note);
        setnote("");
    };

    return (
        <>
        <Headersmall/>
        <br/>
        <div className="addcard">
            <h1>Add new note.</h1>
            <div className="title">
                <input type="text" className="titlebox" id="addtitle" placeholder="Title"/>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div className="note">
                <textarea type="text" className="notebox" id="addtxt" placeholder="Note" onChange = {textchange}/>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <button className="addbtn" id='addbtn' onClick = {savenote}>Save</button>
        </div>
        <br/>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're setting the value of note as an empty string by doing `setnote("")` inside `savenote()` function, you ARE changing the value of the state variable `note`, but it doesn't reflect in the textarea because your textarea input doesn't have a value associated to it. Try adding `value={note}` which will mean that there will be a "set and fetch" relationship between the textarea and the 'note' state variable

```
<textarea
 value={note}
 type="text"
 className="notebox"
 id="addtxt"
 placeholder="Note"
 onChange={textchange}
>
```